# Error deserializing a bundle and casting back to actual class

Tags: java, android, serialization, bundle, deserialization

```
// this is the method referred to below (in activity 1)
public ArrayList<MatchEntry[]> getAllMatchEntries()
    {
        ArrayList<MatchEntry[]> result = new ArrayList<MatchEntry[]>();
        for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)
        {
            result.add(this.get(i).getMatchInfo());
        }
        return result;
    }

/**
 * stores information about a single match
 */
public class MatchEntry implements Serializable
{...}

// Activity 1 - bundling
ArrayList<MatchEntry[]> allMatchEntries = _hadiths.getAllMatchEntries();
b.putSerializable("allMatchEntries", allMatchEntries);
Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.putExtras(b);

// Activity 2 - de-bundling
private ArrayList<MatchEntry[]> _allMatchEntries;
_allMatchEntries = (ArrayList<MatchEntry[]>) bundle.getSerializable("allMatchEntries");

// in fragment adapter, this is where the error occurs
class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    ...

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.a.b.MatchEntry[]
        MatchEntry[] entries = (_allMatchEntries != null) ? _allMatchEntries.get(position) : null;
    }
}

// this is the fragment
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    public static HadithFragment newInstance(int id, MatchEntry[] matchEntries)
    {
        MyFragment fm = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("_id", id);
        args.putSerializable("matchEntries", matchEntries); // store for onCreateView
        fm.setArguments(args);
        return fm;
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // handle highlighting
    MatchEntry[] _matchEntries = (MatchEntry[]) getArguments().getSerializable("matchEntries");
    if(_matchEntries != null && _matchEntries.length > 0)
    {
              ...
    }
}
```

Seriously I do not see what I am doing wrong.

EDIT:

The debugger which I have been using all the time to see whats going on shows a structure like this at de-serialisation:

```
ArrayList<Object[]>
    Object[1]
    Object[1]
    Object[2]
    Object[1]
    Object[2]
        MatchEntry
        MatchEntry
```

This is confusing because I know I serialised an `ArrayList<MatchEntry[]>` as you can see in my code, so why does it have an `ArrayList<Object[]>` at deserialisation? Basically that was the gist of my whole question.

Comment: It looks like you have added an `Object` array to the serialized `ArrayList` at some point.

Comment: Is there a reason you've opted for the slower `Serializable` over the faster `Parcelable`?

Comment: @ChrisHorner well until I get the whole functionality working I did not want to optimize for speed.

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger and check what you want to cast to MatchEntry[]?

Comment: @kupsef I have been using the debugger all the time, please see my edit I think its worth mentioning what the debugger shows.

Comment: Can you also debug to check the elements of the `ArrayList` at the time of serialization?

Comment: I have checked and the deserialization works for me with with type of ArrayList<String[]>. So it should work with any Serializable type, just like with MatchEntry. If you don't want to debug why did you lost the type, then just use the method what I suggested below.

Comment: Well, now I used a custom type what implements Serializable, and I have the same symptoms as you...

Comment: I second that (de-)serialization is working with `ArraList<MatchEntry>`, but not with `ArraList<MatchEntry[]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that you cannot cast Object[] array to any specific array. This a Java specific property.

You have to cast every element in a loop, or you can shorten it this way:

```
Object[] temp = _allMatchEntries.get(position)
MatchEntry[] target = new MatchEntry[temp.length]();
System.arraycopy(temp, 0, target, 0, a.length);
```

Somehow the type is lost, I don't know the reason of it, but its kinda weird. As I said it would work with ArrayList< String[]>, maybe because the String class is a common one and the serializer handles it specially. Someone could shed some light on this one, it really bugs me...

Alternatively you could use ArrayList< ArrayList< MatchEntry>>. This will work, at least I have tested it.

Comment: I will try your alternative with ArrayList<ArrayList<MatchEntry>> and see if it works, and yes this is annoying.

Comment: The alternative of using an `ArrayList<ArrayList<MatchEntry>>` works, and that is what I have marked as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, i guess we are sure that `MatchEntry` is serializable and after

```
b.putSerializable("allMatchEntries", allMatchEntries);
```

the debugger  shows that indeed    `allMatchEntries` is an `ArrayList<MatchEntry[]>` right?

If so, the intent contains a proper serialization, and the problem is de-serializating, probably the error is just that it cannot cast an array, but it can do it item by item, have you tried this?

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
      Object[] temp = (_allMatchEntries != null) ? _allMatchEntries.get(position) : null;
      MatchEntry[] entries = (_allMatchEntries != null) ? _allMatchEntries.get(position) : null;
      for (int i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
            entries[i]=(MatchEntry) temp[i];
       }
      //..
}
```